# SignalR connection crashes and no stream is possible

Tags: angular, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, kestrel

I am experiencing few issues with an application created with SignalR, ASP.Net Core 3.1, Kestrel and Angular 10. Hopefully somebody will be able to help me. I tried searching through the forum for a long time, but couldn’t resolve current bugs.

The application is of a dashboard type – few components can be clicked to filter real time data. Some basic UI components will always be shown and should always get data streamed from hub.

Startup set up:

```
services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
            {
                hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
// Maybe I don’t need those, but connection is dropping very frequently with defaults.
                hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                hubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                hubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
            })
                .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol();
                
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("/data");
            });
```

Server set up:

```
webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
                    {
                        serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 80, listenOptions =>
                        {
                            listenOptions.UseConnectionLogging();
                        });
                        serverOptions.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
                        serverOptions.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate = null;
                        serverOptions.Limits.MinResponseDataRate = null;
                    });
```

Connection set up:

```
private buildHubConnection(uri: string): signalR.HubConnection {
        return new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(uri)
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
            .withAutomaticReconnect({nextRetryDelayInMilliseconds: () => 2000})
            .build();
    }
```

together with:

```
serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 100000;
```

Issues are the following:

Response is way slow until it crashes. Server is pushing data via stream to every component on a dashboard, but it even happens that request reaches timeout (I tested that part with Long Polling, but same delay exists with Web Sockets).

I would expect that data from the server would be pushed back in some normal time which can be covered with transition on UI. Delay is so big that it comes to the request timeout.

With Web Sockets, this is the error message:
`Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server timeout elapsed without receiving a message from the server.'`.

Even when the reconnect is successful, data is not there.

In most of the cases, scenario is long loop of reconnect tries with the following error:
`Information: Connection reconnecting because of error 'Error: Server timeout elapsed without receiving a message from the server.'`.

Even after console log successful reconnect, dataQuery fails saying:

```
Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.
```

This all together is not logical to me. Why would connection be closed if the server should be streaming the data? Can you help me figure out what might be missing, or what could be the issue? Thanks to anyone replying.

Answer (score 1):

> Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server timeout elapsed
> without receiving a message from the server.'

The default timeout value of `serverTimeoutInMilliseconds` is 30,000 milliseconds (30 seconds), if this timeout elapses without receiving any messages from the server, the connection might be terminated with the server timeout error.

> ```
> services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
>             {
>                 hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
> // Maybe I don’t need those, but connection is dropping very frequently with defaults.
>                 hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
>                 hubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
>                 hubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
>             })
>                 .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol();
>                 
> app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
>             {
>                 endpoints.MapControllers();
>                 endpoints.MapHub<LiveDataHub>("/liveData");
>             });
> ```

The issue might relates the above code, you just update the `KeepAliveInterval` setting of your SignalR hub but not change the `serverTimeoutInMilliseconds` value on your client side. And the recommended `serverTimeoutInMilliseconds` value is **double** the `KeepAliveInterval` value. More detail information, see [SignalR
Configure server options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options)